# как сделать ползунок изменяющий два значения "от" и "до"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

привет, я новичок, не понимаю как сделать вот такой ползунок, используя чистый js?

Comment: В гугле есть много решений. Варианты: два инпута range друг на друге, див без инпутов есть [большая ветка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753946/html5-slider-with-two-inputs-possible) по этому поводу, на [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/multi-thumb-sliders-particular-two-thumb-case/) есть пример, в codepen есть несколько примеров [1](https://codepen.io/rendykstan/pen/VLqZGO) И что из этого всего вы пробовали и что не получилось?

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 0):

Если чисто ползунок то: `<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="50">`  [вот почитай](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/range). Чтобы это на что-то влияло зависит от того что тебе надо. вот как получить значение ползунка:

```
document.getElementById("myrange").addEventListener("change", function() {
console.log(this.value);
});
```

[Вот ссылка на то как сделать двойной ползунок на jqery](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range)

[Вот на js](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/)

Comment: на скрине у range должно быть два ползунка: от и до

Comment: Извиняюсь, не заметил

Answer (score -1):

Вот решение на чистом html и css:

https://uiverse.io/Li-Deheng/itchy-octopus-9

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)